# Why don't we define "the derivative" of a univariate function as the average of its directional derivatives?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I just noticed an interesting thing when looking at the derivative of the absolute value function $f(x) = |x|$.  As is well-known, this function is differentiable (in the classical limiting sense) at all points except $x=0$.  Specifically, the directional derivatives of the function for the downward and upward limits are given respectively by:

$$\begin{align}
f_\downarrow'(x) 
&\equiv \lim_{\Delta \downarrow 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta)-f(x)}{\Delta} 
= \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x < 0, \\[6pt]
 1 & \text{if } x \geqslant 0, \\[6pt]
\end{cases} \\[16pt]
f_\uparrow'(x) 
&\equiv \lim_{\Delta \uparrow 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta)-f(x)}{\Delta} 
= \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x \leqslant 0, \\[6pt]
 1 & \text{if } x > 0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases} \\[16pt]
\end{align}$$

At the point $x=0$ we have $f_\downarrow'(x) = 1 \neq -1 = f_\uparrow'(x)$ so the derivative (in its classical sense) does not exist at this point.  However, I have observed that in some applied mathematical fields, it is usual to use the following [weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative) (which is also a valid Radon-Nikodym derivative) as "the derivative" of the function:

$$f'(x) = \text{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if } x < 0, \\[6pt]
 0 & \text{if } x = 0, \\[6pt]
 1 & \text{if } x > 0. \\[6pt]
\end{cases}$$

That is all very well and good, but I just noticed that this weak derivative is the *average of the directional derivatives*.  This leads me to wonder whether it would be useful to define "the derivative" of a univariate function as the average of its directional derivatives *as a general rule*.  The obvious advantage of doing this is that this form of derivative would exist in a broader class of cases than in the classical definition (e.g., in this case), and it would correspond to the one we use in at least the case shown.  Moreover, it is one valid Radon-Nikodym derivative of the function, so it seems that it would give us a concept of "the derivative" that is more specific than the Radon-Nikodym but more general than the classical limiting concept.

I imagine that the drawback would be that it might be misleading to use this kind of Radon-Nikodym derivative in some applications, particularly where we use derivatives to extrapolate a direction for iterative purposes.  Another drawback is that there is no obvious extension to multivariate functions, since there are an infinite number of directions in the latter case (though one could define an average by integrating over all directions I suppose).

In any case, I thought I would ask some of you esteemed experts for specifics of why this method of defining the derivative is not used.

---

**Question:** Why don't we define "the derivative" of a univariate function as the average of its directional derivatives?  Are there any fields/literature where this definition has been used?

Comment: The key idea of calculus is to take a nonlinear function and approximate it locally by a linear function. The absolute value function simply can't be approximated well near $0$ by a linear function, and it seems best to just admit that. But, we can try to generalize the idea of the derivative -- for example, "subgradients" are a useful notion in convex analysis, where a key strategy is to bound functions from below by linear functions.

Comment: That's helpful, but of course we do have broader forms of derivative like the Radon-Nikodym, so that can't be the only reason.  Is there any use for a concept that is in the middle ground?

Comment: Someone else asked this about 9 months ago.  To be honest I can't see what possible advantage anyone could think this would have.  Calculus is to answer questions about behavior and infinitismal ranges and to consider *all* the issues that could arise.  This just seems like averaging everything out and *ignoring* the issues that arise.  If we want to *ignore* issues we can just pretend calculus never was invented and we can just assume everything is estimated on *reeeeeeallly* small but non-zero values.

Comment: Can you link to the other question?

Comment: the only time i can recall using that sgn 0=0 is when i wanted sgn to be odd. Perhaps a distant but related phenomenon is that the fourier series of an otherwise nice function does converge to the average across a jump discontinuity (in particular the fourier series of sgn converges to this representation)

Comment: To answer this question well, I think it might be useful to know when the average of directional derrivatives corresponds to the weak derivative (i.e., under what sufficient/necessary conditions).  I have asked another question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098695/) to that effect.