# When does the average of directional derivatives (for a univariate function) match the weak derivative?

Tags: functions, derivatives

This question relates to another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071557/).  Suppose we have a univariate function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where the directional derivatives $f_\downarrow':\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_\uparrow':\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ exist over the whole domain.  Suppose we then define the "pseudo-derivative" as the average of the directional derivatives:

$$f_*'(x) = \frac{f_\downarrow'(x) + f_\uparrow'(x)}{2}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

I would like to know the circumstances in which this "pseudo-derivative" $f_*'$ is equal to the [weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative) of $f$.  I have noticed that this pseudo-derivative matches the weak derivative in the case of the absolute value function, so I wonder if there is a more general correspondence, or some reasonable sufficient conditions for correspondence.

---

**My Question:** Under what conditions on $f$ will this "pseudo-derivative" be a weak derivative of $f$?

Comment: I suspect your absolute value function example could be extended to something like "differentiable except on countably many points," since the weak derivative is defined through integrals, which don't care about countable sets.

Comment: @angryavian: Great suggestion.  Which leads me to another simplifying question: since the directional derivatives are assumed to exist over the entire domain, is it possible that the directional derivatives could be different to each other (i.e., function is non-differentiable in the classical sense) over an uncountable set?  My intuition is telling me this is impossible, but I know this stuff can get thorny.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in order to ensure that a weak derivative of $f$ exists, let's assume that $f$ is in the [Lebesgue space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) $L^1$.  Following the suggestion by [angryavian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43949/) in the comments, I am going to try to show that differentiability except at a countable number of points is a sufficient condition for $f_*'$ to be a weak derivative of $f$.

---

**Theorem:** Consider a function $f \in L^1$ and suppose that the directional derivatives $f_\downarrow'$ and $f_\uparrow'$ exist everywhere in the domain.  If $f$ is differentiable in the classical sense (i.e., the directional derivates are equal) except at a countable set of points, then the pseudo-derivative $f_*'$ is a weak derivative of $f$.

**Proof:** Since the directional derivatives exist over all points in the domain, we may unambiguously define the set of values $\mathscr{T} \equiv \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | f_\downarrow'(x) \neq f_\uparrow'(x) \}$, where the classical derivative of $f$ does not exist.  We will denote the classical derivative by $f'$, noting that this function is well-defined over the domain $\mathbb{R}-\mathscr{T}$.  It is trivial to show that $f'(x) = f_*'(x)$ over all $x \in \mathbb{R}-\mathscr{T}$.

Consider an arbitrary infinitely differentiable function $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and points $a<b$ with $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)=0$.  Under the conditions of the theorem $\mathscr{T}$ is countable so $f'$ exists almost everywhere over $[a,b]$.  Consequently, we can apply integration by parts over the range $[a,b]-\mathscr{T}$ to get:

$$\begin{align}
\Bigg[ f(x) \varphi(x) \Bigg]_{x=a}^{x=b} 
&= \int \limits_{[a,b] - \mathscr{T}} f(x) \varphi'(x) \ dx + \int \limits_{[a,b] - \mathscr{T}} f'(x) \varphi(x) \ dx \\[12pt]
&= \int \limits_{[a,b]} f(x) \varphi'(x) \ dx + \int \limits_{[a,b]} f_*'(x) \varphi(x) \ dx \\[12pt]
&= \int \limits_a^b f(x) \varphi'(x) \ dx + \int \limits_a^b f_*'(x) \varphi(x) \ dx. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Since this holds for all $\varphi$ with the stipulated conditions, this confirms the requirements for $f_*'$ to be a weak derivative of $f$.  $\blacksquare$